# Does 2-chloro-1,3-dinitrobenzene show resonance?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

I am preparing for my exam, and then I stuck up here. The answer to this question given by my teacher was

> No, this doesn't show resonance because there are two bulky groups alongside chlorine, due to this chlorine will leave the plane and as we know resonance is a planar phenomenon, it won't show resonance

My question to you is:

Why did chlorine leave the plane on the first place? And what is the whole concept behind it? Please help me with it.

My guess to this is that since these two groups are really big and bulky, and are present near Chlorine, they take up almost all the space around which causes chlorine to leave the plane.

Comment: In one line, it's **Steric Inhibition of Resonance**.

Answer (score 1):

2-chloro-1,3-dinitrobenzene is shown below:

[image]

I believe your question is referring to the lack of conjugation between the nitro groups and the aromatic ring. this is best shown in an X-ray crystal structure such as this one:

[image]

https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=722415

Due to the sterics between the nitro groups and the chloro substituent, the nitro groups cannot adopt a conformation planar with the ring. This prevents the $\pi$ system of the nitro group from achieving substantial overlap with the $\pi$ system of the ring and prevents full conjugation of the electrons. The sterics are better seen in a spacefilling view:

[image]

So, it is not the chloro group that is out of the plane, but rather the nitro groups.

Comment: That 3D rendition of the molecule's structure is not exactly an "X-ray crystal structure".

Comment: @William R. Ebenezer. I will take it down if I am mistaken. It came from the Cambridge crystallographic database. Check the link and I will remove if you could explain my mistake.

Comment: @Withnail thankyou so much. I understand it now !

Comment: @Withnail But hey, doesn't it go against common sense?

Comment: @Withnail I can't find it, could you be more specific?

Comment: @william R Ebenezer. The link to CCDC is in the answer. https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=722415

Comment: @Withnail yes, I have visited the link, but couldn't find that term.

Comment: @William R. Ebenezer. The CCDC is an X-ray crystallography database. That image is from a structure determined by Marten et al. and deposited in 2010

Comment: Yes, but that does not mean that image is an "x-ray crystal structure". Do you know what XRD/XRC is?

Comment: The image is based on calculations (maybe aided by XRD etc), but afaik it is wrong terminology to say that image is an "xray crystal structure".

Comment: I am not a crystallographer, but I have had structures of compounds that I have synthesized determined by crystallographers. So far as I can tell, that entry in the CCDC comes from a single crystal XRD experiment. I have not read the original paper, just the entry in the CCDC. Please let me know if you know otherwise about where it comes from.